# mvn running in container with HOME=/ seems to ignore /.m2

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins

We run mvn (v3.8.2) in a container, and we realized that the .m2 directory we thought it was using is likely being ignored.

Inside the container, HOME is set to "/".  I've mapped the .m2 directory on the host, which is fully populated, to "/" in the container.  I ran some shell commands inside the container, and I can see /.m2/repository perfectly fine.

This is running inside a scripted Jenkins pipeline using "docker.image(...).inside(...) { ... }".

In the "inside" block, I ran "mvn -X ..." and teed the output to a file.

In the output, I see a line like this:

```
[DEBUG] Using local repository at ...@2/?/.m2/repository
```

where I've elided the full path with "...".  The "@2" is at the end of the directory name, and I have no idea why it prints "?" there.  As far as I can tell, this directory does not exist, but the directory ending with "@2" DOES exist, and that is the current directory in the container.  When the mvn command proceeds, it downloads many artifacts that I'm pretty certain would be in the local .m2/repository.

From what I understand, mvn will look for ~/.m2/repository.  It doesn't appear to be doing that.  It seems to instead look for it in some variation of the CURRENT directory.

I even tried to add a symlink in the container from /.m2 to pwd/.m2, but it still says in the -X output that it's looking for "...@2/?/.m2/repository".

Comment: What is the value of the user.home system property?

Comment: The answer is both unsurprising and perplexing at the same time: "[DEBUG] properties used {..., user.home=?, ...".

Comment: Perhaps another thing that would be useful to point out is that the result of "whoami" in the container gets this: + whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 81050

Comment: Would it make any difference if I added "-Duser.home=/" to the mvn command line, or will it ignore that?

Comment: That’s why.  You need to run as a user which is listed in /etc/passwd

Comment: We're running mvn in a container, which is becoming a common practice. I don't know how practical it will be to fix what user is running.  In any case, my hack idea appears to fix it.  I have to do more inspections to see whether it's actually updating the shared maven repo.

Comment: You should not see this - use a better image.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, either part.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the .m2 repo as volume i.e. map the local maven repo. Something like this: `args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'` The advantage of this is it will let you reuse the local artifacts instead of downloading them everytime.

Comment: What docker image do you ask jenkins to use? Is that image compatible with the docker container actually running it?